# Fixed Array and when it reaches the limit remove elements from the end - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon! I am looking to create a fixed array of length 5, where I want to store recent viewed ids. And when it reaches the limit to delete elements from the end.

For example:

```
array = ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'] // Array of 5 with ID's
```

When I add an id the array want to be like this:

```
array = ['6', '5', '4', '3', '2'];
```

And keep going.

Thank you so much for taking your time and I respect your help.

Comment: What have you already tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: try yourarray.splice(-1,1) , it will remove last element from an array. you can add this code after you push a new element in to the array

Comment: I tried to do it hard coded. But I want to make it a little bit more simple and I was looking for other efficient alternatives. As @bambam did it, clean and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a little class managing the ids for you

```js
class Ids {
  constructor() {
    this._store = [];
  }

  add(id) {
    if (this.store.length > 4) this._store.shift();
    this._store.push(id);
  }

  get store() {
    return this._store;
  }
}

const id = new Ids();
id.add(1);
id.add(2);
id.add(3);
id.add(4);
id.add(5);
id.add(6);
id.add(7);
id.add(8);
id.add(9);
console.log(id.store);
```

Answer (score 5):

Heres a function that takes an id, removes the last element if there is more than 5 and then add the id to the start of the array.

```
function addId(id, array) {
  if (array.length === 5) {
    array.pop();
  }
  array = array.splice(0, 0, id);
  return array;
}
```

Comment: love the simplicity, but line 5 is incorrect, array.splice returns deleted element. Array is modified by reference, we don't need the returned value.

So what we want here is

function addId(id, array) {
  if (array.length === 5) {
    array.pop();
  }
  array.splice(0, 0, id);
  return array;
}

Answer (score 2):

You could unshift the array and adjust the length by the minimum of the wanted length and the old length.

```js
function unshift(array, value) {
    array.unshift(value);
    array.length = Math.min(array.length, 5);
    return array;
}

var array = [],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(unshift(array, i).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to do this and a lot more. For example here's a simple proxy that keeps an array to only 5 elements. This has the advantage that it still acts like an array with `length` and `map` and all the other stuff.

This is set so when you `unshift`, extra elements will fall off the end. You could of course do the opposite with `push`. You can also manually assign by index so long as the index is less than 5.

```js
var limitedArrayProxy = {
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
      if (!isNaN(property)){
          if(parseInt(property) < 5){
            target[property] = value;
      }
    }
      return true;
    }
  };
  
var limitArray = new Proxy( [], limitedArrayProxy );

// push on a few elements 
limitArray.push(1, 2, 3)
console.log(limitArray)

// unshift a few more
limitArray.unshift(5, 4)
console.log(limitArray)

// now that length is 5 unshift will add to front
// and the last element will fall off
limitArray.unshift(10)
console.log(limitArray)

// manually change index 2
limitArray[2] = "manually changed"
console.log(limitArray)

// it won't let you push more than five
limitArray.push(20)
console.log(limitArray)

// can't add an index of 5 or greater
limitArray[5] = "overflow"
console.log("still 5 element:", limitArray)

// it still acts like an array 
// with length and methods like map
console.log("length", limitArray.length)
console.log("map squares", limitArray.map(i => i**2))
```

Comment: That is seriously cool. I can't believe I've never come across it!

Comment: I wonder how a `push()` version would look like. However, this works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'];

console.log(array);
queue('6');
console.log(array);

function queue(number){
    array.pop(); //removes last element from array
    array.splice(0, 0, number);//puts new number in first spot
}
```

This should do the trick. Any time you needed to add an element to the array you would just call that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Array's `push` method to remove the last element of the Array with `Array.prototype.pop` if its length is equal to the maximum length that you want to the Array to be.

```js
var array = ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'];
array.maxlength = 5;
array.push = function(elem){
  if(this.length==this.maxlength){
    this.pop();
  }
  return [].unshift.call(this, elem);
}
array.push('6');
console.log(array);
```